# Generate waveform via GPIB in CAPL

Tags: capl, gpib

I have a simulation that generates a waveform using a Power Supply Controlled using a GPIB interface. The problem with this is that the waveform frequency is limited by the speed of the PC/Power Supply response, since it generates each point by a VOLT command (SCPI).

I have heard that you can upload CSV files to an Agilent PS (N7973A) via GPIB and execute it. How is that possible? Is there a dll or a SCPI command that can be used to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, look at "Programming an Arbitrary Waveform" (manual p.105) and [SOURce:]ARB  commands (p.271)

Comment: I found exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!